# Multiple updates to an array in a redux reducer

Tags: javascript, action, state, redux

I'm creating a new action on a Redux store. 
I have a list of items which all have a property of "overlayVis". I want to set all of these to true except the specified Id.  My current implementation is

```
case ITEM_OVERLAY_TOGGLE:
  // object to be updated and returned   
  var returnObj = state.data;

  state.data.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === action.id) {
      returnObj = Object.assign({}, ...state, {
        data: [
          ...state.data.slice(0, item.id),
          Object.assign({}, ...state.data[item.id], {overlayVis: false}),
          ...state.data.slice(item.id + 1)]
      });
    } else if (!item.overlayVis) {
      returnObj = Object.assign({}, ...state, {
        data: [
          ...state.data.slice(0, item.id),
          Object.assign({}, ...state.data[item.id], {overlayVis: true}),
          ...state.data.slice(item.id + 1)]
      });
    }
  });

  return returnObj;
```

Each iteration overrides the previous iteration so only one change is made each time the action is run.  I have attempted to use "state" and "returnObj " instead of "...state" but it has not worked. I've not posted on here in a long time but I'm am out of ideas.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your map function can be changed to look like this. I can only take a guess from here, but can you see if this works?

Map function is used to transform objects in an array and you need to return a value in the map function for the transform to happen. The transformed values are stored in a new array called newData. That is returned outside.

```
case ITEM_OVERLAY_TOGGLE:
    var newData = state.data.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === action.id) {
      return  {
            ...item,
            overlayVis:false
        }
    } else {
        return {
              ...item,
              overlayVis : true
        }
    }
  });

 return {
    ...state,
    data: newData
  }
```

**Edit**: If action.id is also the index of the array, try this

```
case ITEM_OVERLAY_TOGGLE:
  // object to be updated and returned   

  return {
     ...state,
     data : [
         ...state.data.slice(0,action.id).map(i=>{ i.overlayVis = true, return i;  }),
         state.data[action.id].overlayVis=false,
         ...state.data.slice(action.id+1).map(i=>{ i.overlayVis = true, return i;  })
     ]
  };
```

Comment: I think I just had a eureka moment... things seem a lot clearer! Thanks, seems to work perfectly.

Comment: But wait... this will recreate all of the items again from scratch?

Comment: Yes, it does. But if you don't do that, the references which your React Components hold will remain the same, which means the Component thinks nothing has changed. Its really important that you change references on every mutation.

Comment: Also, the spread operator is shallow, which means complex objects nested within objects are not recreated. http://www.es6fiddle.net/inciq40i/

Comment: Action.Id is the Index, so we are back where I started in the OP it seems

Comment: If action.id is in fact the index, why are you comparing it with item.id ?

Comment: Hi Appreciate the response but this is a similar solution to the OP, it's just only making changes to the item associated with the passed in index.

Comment: The first solution presented here looks right, although probably mutating more elements than necessary. It's changing all of the elements, not just the one at the passed index. The second solution, under "Edit", is a mess.

Comment: HI JIMM, the first solution seemed perfect until I saw that it updated all items. That can't happen, the items can be complex and there are a lot. I only want to rerender the action item and any item that was previously false.    (mess lol)